Troubles recording a sound using SoX with options - can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not applicable
I recently tried to record a sound using the onboard mic of my Dell Precision 3571 running on Ubuntu 22.04, with the sox command and a precise set of options (default sound card, 2 channels, 192 kHz frame rate, 32 bit signed integer little endian, wav file, for 2 seconds)
$ sox -d -c 2 -r 192k -b 32 -e signed-integer -L -t wav test.wav trim 0 2
Although test.wav was created,I got the following error, and the options I was looking for were not used:
sox WARN alsa: can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not applicable
Input File     : 'default' (alsa)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:00:02.05 [00:00:00.00] Out:384k  [      |      ]        Clip:0    
Done.

I then checked on various forums (e.g. https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/) and wiki about the sox WARN alsa... error, which lead me to reinstall ALSA, to check the ouput of the command $ sudo alsa-info, and to make sure that the default sound card is configured for ALSA in /etc/asound.conf as:
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw           
    card 0
}

given that $ arecord -l gives:
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3204 Analog [ALC3204 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Still, my problem remains the same, and I can't record a sound as I expect to.
For the record, the simplistic $ sudo rec test.wav returns rec FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured even after writing the configuration file, and though I can otherwise perfectly use my onboard mic with videoconferencing apps.
Any advice about how to solve this issue ?

After some more investigation, the following solved my issue:

install libsox-fmt-all: $ sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-all
reordering the options in the call of the sox command: $ sox -c 2 -r 192k -b 32 -e signed-integer -L -d -t wav test.wav trim 0 2

Now I no longer have the error

sox WARN alsa: can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not applicable

and the options are taken into account as I wanted.
I believe that creating the configuration file /etc/asound.conf as explained in my question was also necessary to setup the default recording device required for option -d.
